# Am I able to use the function 'count()' to find the amount of upper cases in a password? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, passwords, uppercase

When I enter the code below, it says:

> TypeError: must be str, not list

Does this mean I cannot use the function count() or is there another way I could program it?

```
password = "CheeseMakesMeHappy"
uppercase =["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
print (password.count(uppercase))
```

Comment: "count() method searches the substring in the given string and returns how many times the substring is present in it." Here you are providing list as an argument to the count function instead of substring which will raise "TypeError: must be str, not list
"

Comment: Suggestion: `import string` then use `string.ascii_uppercase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go through every character in the password and check if it is an uppercase character.
For example:

```
password = "FoOoObA"
print(len([c for c in password if c.isupper()]))
>> 4
```

Another method is using sets and bitmasks to count the number of unique uppercase characters.

```
password = "CheeseMakesMeHappy"
uppercase = set(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"])
print(len(set(password)&uppercase))
>> 3
```

The `set` solution however will only count UNIQUE characters, but in the case of password strength metering that might not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the method `count()` expects a string object. Right now, with this line `(password.count(uppercase))`, you are effectively passing an Array object to your function. See zeraien's answer for a good solution.